# How to remove UITableView separator (Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uitableview

In a prior Xcode versions, settings the **separator style to none** for the `UITableView` via the **interface builder** used to solve the problem.

[image]

**But, this is no longer works in Xcode 7. How to remove/hide the `UITableView` Seperator in Xcode 7?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Xcode 7 is no longer picking the separator style from the interface
>   builder. This may also be related to the iOS 9 SDK as the Base SDK.

**But, it always can be achieved programmatically:**

```
// objective-c
[tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

// swift
tableview.separatorStyle = .None
```

Related, this is also applied on the UITableView background color:

```
// objective-c
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

// swift
tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Answer (score 0):

In table init (viewDidLoad) you can adding this line:

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```